# Flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1

Tags: flutter, api, listview, flutter-layout

I am creating an app using flutter that will display a list from an api. Part of the functionality of the app is to show details of the data I get from the api. this is the data from the api

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "James",
    "last_name": "May",
    "gender": "male",
    "phone_number": "00123456",
    "email": "james.may@example.com",
    "houses": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "house_name": "WEST_COMPLEX",
        "house_size": "1000 square foot"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "house_name": "EAST_COMPLEX",
        "house_size": "28000 square foot"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Jenny",
    "last_name": "Zamunda"
    "gender": "female",
    "phone_number": "00345678",
    "email": "jenny.z@example.com",
    "houses": []
  }
]
```

My app displays this list using a list view and I have implemented an ontap fuctionality to display more information about one person in a new page.

I am encountering an error when I want to view more details about the second person. This is the error I am getting

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:farm_manager_app/screens/home.dart:105
#2      MaterialPageRoute.buildContent
package:flutter/…/material/page.dart:54
#3      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage
package:flutter/…/material/page.dart:107
#4      _ModalScopeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:840
...
```

This is the ontap code to open the details page with the required information

```
                            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => OwnerDetails(
                                  id: id.toString(),
                                  firstName: owner.firstName,
                                  lastName: owner.lastName,
                                  gender: owner.gender,
                                  email: owner.email,
                                  phoneNumber: owner.phoneNumber,
                                  houseID: owner.houses[index].id.toString(),
                                  houseName: owner.houses[index].houseName,
                                  houseSize: owner.houses[index].houseSize,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

What could be the issue

EDIT

parseJSON

```
List<Owners> ownersFromJson(String str) => List<Owners>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Owners.fromJson(x)));

String ownersToJson(List<Owners> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Owners {
    Owners({
        this.id,
        this.firstName,
        this.lastName,
        this.gender,
        this.phoneNumber,
        this.email,
        this.houses,
    });

    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String gender;
    String phoneNumber;
    String email;
    List<House> houses;

    factory Owners.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Owners(
        id: json["id"],
        firstName: json["first_name"],
        lastName: json["last_name"],
        gender: json["gender"],
        phoneNumber: json["phone_number"],
        email: json["email"],
        houses: List<House>.from(json["houses"].map((x) => House.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "gender": gender,
        "phone_number": phoneNumber,
        "email": email,
        "houses": List<dynamic>.from(houses.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class House {
    House({
        this.id,
        this.houseName,
        this.houseSize,
    });

    int id;
    String houseName;
    String houseSize;

    factory House.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => House(
        id: json["id"],
        houseName: json["house_name"],
        houseSize: json["house_size"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "house_name": houseName,
        "house_size": houseSize,
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you add `parseJson` and before this code snippet. How you are using `owner`.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added parseJson